# How to create "check/uncheck all" with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have a button, to check or uncheck all checkbox.

This is my Markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<button type="button" id="addAll">add all</button>
<button type="button" id="removeAll">remove all</button>
```

And this is my script:

```
$("#addAll").click(function() {
  $("#container input:checkbox").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
$("#removeAll").click(function() {
  $("#container input:checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
});
```

But it does not work as expected:

- Check all, works
- Uncheck all, works
- Check all again, nothing happens

What could be the error?

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14z6os01/1/)

Comment: @CBroe  there seems no other question on SO that points to this issue. May be the accepted answer is duplicate, but this question doesnt deserve to be flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#addAll").click(function() {
  $("#container input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
});
$("#removeAll").click(function() {
  $("#container input:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
});
```

---

This is probably a bug in jquery, because using native setAttribute and removeAttribute works fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/jz5p57k9/

I have opened a bug for Jquery team, you can follow it here:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3242#issuecomment-234315378

For the difference between .attr and .prop, please see this question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Question is about solving problem of current code. You should solve problem instead changing it.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Why does my method not work?

Comment: Without an explanation, this is a low-quality answer.

Comment: Searching hard for it @squint.

Comment: @rishabh I edited your question and added a link to a question that explains the difference between attr/propr

Comment: @CBroe: Your edit doesn't explain why `.attr/removeAttr()` not work.

Comment: @squint: If you read the whole thing, and understand what the difference between attributes and properties is, it should.